# How can I update a text based on user input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, replace

I know this is probably simple, but how do you update a text based on a user's input?

For example, I have an email template that starts out like this:

*Greetings,
My name is ***_*_** and I'm the author of ***_*__** which is available on Amazon.com.*

I would like to create some simple input fields for the user to insert their name and the title of their book. There are several more inputs as well. I would just need the final output to give them the full text of the template with their own info inserted in the right places, based on what they submit.

What is the easiest and simplest way to accomplish this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add tags to indicate the applicable programming language and/or program/tool you're using.

Comment: I was hoping to use javascript, I'm less familiar with PHP...but open to help using any language, as long as it's relatively easy to setup for a noob (I am a beginner).

Comment: @ashloren if you want to store those data into db you have to use some programming language such as PHP,.net etc

Comment: google for an ajax tutorial and work through it. this should get you going already, but if you want to get further you may want to dive into jquery or some other framework that builds upon javascript/ajax and is easier to use.

Comment: I don't think I need to store them...I just want the text to update once on the screen based on their input so they can copy and paste the text into an email...is storing the data necessary for something like that? Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Meh, I am spoiling you. http://jsfiddle.net/MfX29/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find an easer way you can use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.my-inputs').each(function() {
        $(this).on('keyup', function() {
            var name = $('#name').val() == '' ? '___' : $('#name').val();
            var book = $('#book').val() == '' ? '___' : $('#book').val();
            $('#result').html("*Greetings, My name is " + name + " and I'm the author of " + book + " which is available on Amazon.com.*");
        });
    });
});
```

`http://jsfiddle.net/XEzBw/`

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are you searching for a simple format method, and for this you have to use any plugin.

Otherwise:

```
<input type="text" id="inputName"></input>
<input type="text" id="inputAuthor"></input>

var name = $('#inputName').val();
var author = $('#inputAuthor').val();
var t = "*Greetings, My name is " + name + " I'm the author of " + author + " which is available on Amazon.com.";
```

You can try [DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/xuzVw/1/).

Comment: Note that this will not update automatically; you need to insert this into some function and bind it to some event (eg: "change" of either input or "press" of some button).

Comment: Yes I know, in the fiddle, in fact, instructions is bindend on button click!

Comment: Right, but just for anyone skimming and not looking for a fiddle link. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
$('button').click(function () {
                    var str = 'Greetings, My name is ' + $('#name').val() + 'and I\'m the author of ' + $('#book').val() + ' which is available on Amazon.com.';
                    $('#template').html(str);
                });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7bLJK/